# PostgreSQL LOGGED and UNLOGGED table performance comparison with LOCK TABLE usage

Tags: postgresql, locking

I am trying to measure `UPDATE` speed on `LOGGED` and `UNLOGGED` tables in PostgreSQL(10.3). I want to use `LOCK TABLE` to prevent other applications from interfering with each other.

If `UPDATE` is performed without using `LOCK TABLE`, I get ~ 1K for the `LOGGED` table, ~ 4K for the `UNLOGGED` table.

If `UPDATE` is performed using `LOCK TABLE`, the results are the same for both table types.

Why does `LOCK TABLE` return the same result in both table types?

My PL/pgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.myfunction(user_id integer, unitprice numeric(10,6), 
            islock boolean, useunlogged boolean) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare howMuch integer;
begin       
    if islock then
        if useunlogged then 
            LOCK TABLE credittable_unlogged IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
        else
            LOCK TABLE credittable IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
        end if;
    end if;
    if useunlogged then     
        select (credit_amount/unitprice)::integer into howMuch from credittable where userid=user_id and credit_amount>=unitprice;
        if howMuch is null then 
            select 0 into howMuch;
        else
            update credittable set credit_amount=credit_amount-unitprice where userid=user_id;
        end if;    
    else 
        select (credit_amount/unitprice)::integer into howMuch from credittable_unlogged where userid=user_id and credit_amount>=unitprice;
        if howMuch is null then 
           select 0 into howMuch;
        else
            update credittable_unlogged set credit_amount=credit_amount-unitprice where userid=user_id;
        end if;  
    end if;
    RETURN howMuch;
 end;
 $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
 ALTER FUNCTION public.myfunction(integer, numeric, boolean, boolean)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

My Java code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int counter = 0;        
    while ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) < 1000000000L) {
        CallableStatement callst = null;
        try {
            String sql = "{? = call public.myfunction(?,?,?,?) }";
            callst = con.prepareCall(sql);
            callst.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            callst.setInt(2, 123456);
            callst.setBoolean(3, (i > 2));
            callst.setBoolean(4, (i%2 != 0));
            callst.setBigDecimal(3, BigDecimal.valueOf(0.001));
            callst.execute();
            int howMuch = callst.getInt(1);                
            counter++;                
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (callst != null) {
                callst.close();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Counter :"+counter);
}
```

Comment: There is not difference when you perform your test in single thread environment, cause nobody waits on lock

Comment: Yes, but why is the speed of the unlogged table slowed down here?

Comment: Because unlogged tables don't generate WAL. Read more in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) (section `UNLOGGED`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of what you are measuring here is client-server latency and PL/pgSQL execution.

The difference is caused by the necessity to sync WAL to disk.

If you use an unlogged table, and you don't use the `LOCK` statement, no WAL is written, and nothing has to be sync'ed at `COMMIT` time.

Explicit table locks cause a WAL record to be written, so `COMMIT` still has to sync WAL, and you lose the advantage you have from an unlogged table.

You can use `pg_waldump` to examine the WAL files, then you'll see what transaction log records are written.

But I can show it to you with my PostgreSQL v11, built with `-DWAL_DEBUG`.

This is my test table:

```
postgres=# \d t
             Unlogged table "public.t"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           |          |
```

Here an `INSERT` without `LOCK TABLE`:

```
postgres=# SET wal_debug=on;
SET
postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=# INSERT INTO t VALUES (100);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# COMMIT;
LOG:  INSERT @ 0/166BFB8:  - Transaction/COMMIT: 2018-05-18 20:34:20.060635+02
STATEMENT:  COMMIT;
COMMIT
```

There was a commit, but no WAL flush.

```
postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=# LOCK TABLE t;
LOG:  INSERT @ 0/166C038:  - Standby/LOCK: xid 569 db 13344 rel 16384 
STATEMENT:  LOCK TABLE t;
LOCK TABLE
postgres=# INSERT INTO t VALUES (101);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# COMMIT;
LOG:  INSERT @ 0/166C138:  - Transaction/COMMIT: 2018-05-18 20:36:15.419081+02
STATEMENT:  COMMIT;
LOG:  xlog flush request 0/166C138; write 0/166BFF0; flush 0/166BFF0
STATEMENT:  COMMIT;
COMMIT
```

Now we have a WAL flush, and that is the expensive part.

You see that a `Standby/LOCK` record was written.

One way to get around that is to reduce `wal_level` to `minimal` and `max_wal_senders` to `0`, then these WAL records don't have to be written. But then you cannot have WAL archiving and point-in-time recovery.

The other workaround is to use a lower lock level than `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`. That should be fine unless you absolutely have to block readers.

Comment: Are you sure about that using explicit locks cause WAL records to be written in case of unlogged tables? It sounds strange to me, cause there is no any reason to write WAL records for unlogged tables even under explicit lock. Please provide an example or documentation link

Comment: I have added proof.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example! But could you explain necessity of WAL writing for unlogged table in case of explicit locking? It's not helpful neither for recovery nor for replication. It looks like unneeded overhead and implementation flaw

Comment: Good question. Sorry that it took me so long to reply. I agree that it seems to be unnecessary, and I've [submitted a patch](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1527172391.2837.41.camel@cybertec.at) to the Hackers list. If there is a reply, it might be enlightening.

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you